# NativeScript with Angular+TypeScript vs NativeScript with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript, mobile-application

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using  NativeScript with Angular+TypeScript and NativeSCript with JavaScript. I want to know which would be better approach in terms of difficulty and Performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is compiled to Javascript, so there are no performance impact between the two.

If you know C# or Java, you already know most of the Typescript. 
Typescript adds... types to variables and objects, which makes your code much more stable by providing your IDE with the necessary informations to warn you about eventual bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Angular already then you can reuse your knowledge/concept developing Nativescript with Angular. For example routing in NativeScript Angular is the same as Angular you just have to use a different module but with the same API + You can share codes (services) between your Angular browser app and Nativescript Angular app.

But it is true in the other direction as well. 
Let's assume you don't know Angular yet, but you start developing Nativescript with Angular. You learn how to develop Angular browser apps as well, 
but maybe the learning curve would be steeper because you have to learn new concepts.